# TSC TDP-225 and C# PrintQueue Status

Tags: c#, status, thermal-printer

I am using a TSC TDP-225, have installed the drivers from Seagull's site and would like to read printer status in c# using PrintDialog.PrintQueue.QueueStatus. However, it seems like the Windows spooler is not able to read any status, just constantly None. Have I overlooked a driver or is there some plugin to get status from this printer, that is needed?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out status monitoring needs to be turned on manually from the hardware options of the printer in Windows settings.